# Changing the value of an attribute in code at runtime

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have this XAML and at run-time I would  like to know how can I change the value of the MaximumRowsOrColumns attribute which is an attribute of the WrapGrid object:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="LayoutRoot" IsTabStop="True">
    <ItemsControl Name="m_pageContainer" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="50" Width="40" Fill="Pink" />
        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="50" Width="40" Fill="YellowGreen" />
        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="50" Width="40" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="50" Width="40" Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="50" Width="40" Fill="Yellow" />
        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="50" Width="40" Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="50" Width="40" Fill="Gray" />
        <Rectangle Margin="10,10,10,10" Height="50" Width="40" Fill="LightBlue" />
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have been searching in vain for a way to do this in C# or C++/CX.

Thanks

Roger

Comment: Have you tried binding it's value to something in your ViewModel or your equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" MaximumRowsOrColumns="{Binding MaxRowsOrColumns}"/>
```

This assumes you have a property called `MaxRowsOrColumns` in your datacontext (you should add this).  Then all you have to do is change the value of your property.